# Vector field/potential and integral curve?

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

> Let $ω \in Ω^1\left(\Bbb R^2\right)$ with $ω=e^x\cdot \sin   \left(y\right) dx + e^x \cdot \cos   \left(y\right) dy$
>
> $\left(1\right)$Show that $ω $ has got a vector potential and calculate it
>
> $\left(2\right)$ Calculate the line integral $∫_γω$ over the curve $γ:\left[0,1\right]→ \Bbb R^2 ,t\mapsto\left(t,\arctan  \left(t\right)\right)$

For $\left(1\right)$:
Would it suffices if $dω=0?$ if so, then how do I find $dω$ and if not, what do I have to do ?

$∫ e^x \cdot \sin   \left(y\right) dx= e^x \cdot \sin   \left(y\right)+c_1\left(y\right)$

$\Rightarrow\ \frac{∂ \left(e^x \cdot \sin   \left(y\right)+c_1\left(y\right)\right)}{∂ y}=e^x\cdot \cos   \left(y\right) =e^x \cdot \cos   \left(y\right)+c_1'\left(y\right)$

$\Rightarrow c_1\left(y\right)=k \in \Bbb R$

$\Rightarrow f\left(x,y\right)=e^x\sin   \left(y\right)$ is a vector potential

For $\left(2\right):$

$∫_γω=∫_0^1df=f\left(γ\left(1\right)\right)-f\left(γ\left(0\right)\right)=f\left(1,\frac{π}{4}\right)-f\left(0,0\right)=\frac{e\sqrt2}{2}$ Is that right or wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To show that $\omega = df$ for some $f$ it's enough to show that $d\omega = 0$ (since $\Bbb R^2$ is simply connected). In this case, though, we actually want to find $f$, as you have done, so there's no gain in computing $d\omega$.

Comment: @Travis,OK, so for showing that $\omega$ has got a potential vector what have I to write down ?

Comment: You've basically done the calculation already: If $\omega = df$, then expanding gives $\omega = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$, so we're looking to solve the system $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = e^x \sin y, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = e^x \cos y$, which you've solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote: "$∫ e^x \cdot \sin \left(y\right) dx= e^x \cdot \sin \left(y\right) \left(1+x\right)+c_1\left(y\right)$"

But this is false !

We have $∫ e^x \cdot \sin \left(y\right) dx= e^x \cdot \sin \left(y\right)+c_1\left(y\right)$

Comment: Thank you haven't noticed it.